# How can I attach to a WinRT event dynamically?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, .net-4.5

I want to use MVVM in a WinRT (Windows 8) app, and one of my requirements is to be able to hook events up to commands (`ICommand`). This means I have to dynamically add a handler to a WinRT event. There is a nice [explanation of how to do that here](http://www.camronbute.com/2012/06/binding-to-event-at-runtime-in-windows.html), but my problem is that the handler type is not known at compile time (ie. it is not always `RoutedEventHandler` as in that example).

I started to write a generic implementation of that code, where I build the delegates using expression trees. That part works. My problem is that invoking `WindowsRuntimeMarshal.AddEventHandler` dynamically fails:

```
var rtMarshalType = typeof (WindowsRuntimeMarshal);
var eventHandlerMethod = rtMarshalType.GetRuntimeMethods().Single(x => x.IsStatic && x.Name == "AddEventHandler");
MethodInfo closedAddMethod = eventHandlerMethod.MakeGenericMethod(handlerType);
closedAddMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] {add, remove, handler});
```

This fails on the `Invoke` call and throws an InvalidOperationException with the message:

> The API
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeMarshal.AddEventHandler[ItemClickEventHandler](System.Func`2[Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemClickEventHandler,System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.EventRegistrationToken],
>   System.Action`1[System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.EventRegistrationToken],
>   Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemClickEventHandler)' cannot be used on the
>   current platform. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248273
>   for more information.

I know I have the right types, because when I replace the above 4 lines of code with this (hard-coding the event handler type, which is not what I want), then the code works and the event gets attached as expected:

```
WindowsRuntimeMarshal.AddEventHandler<ItemClickEventHandler>(add, remove, handler);
```

For reference, the three parameters is defined as follows (to be sure, it is not a problem with my expression tree building code, I am currently using the explicit definition of these delegates even when trying to dynamic invoke `AddEventHandler`, still failing):

```
Func<ItemClickEventHandler, EventRegistrationToken> add =
    a => (EventRegistrationToken) eventInfo.AddMethod.Invoke(instance, new object[] {a});
Action<EventRegistrationToken> remove = a => eventInfo.RemoveMethod.Invoke(instance, new object[] {a});
ItemClickEventHandler handler = (s, args) => command.Execute(args);
```

Why does the call fail when invoked via reflection and not when I call it directly ?

Is there an alternate solution for dynamically attaching a WinRT event, when the type of event handler is not known at compile time ?

Comment: I should add, using Reactive Extensions to accomplish this, which is suggested in some posts found via Google, is not an option for me. I don't want that reference (And more importantly, I would like to understand _why_ this fails).

Comment: Are you using the Windows 8 RTM or one of the preview releases?  (I ask because the link in the error message appears to be dead; it goes directly to the MSDN front page.)

Comment: Win8 RTM release. And I too noticed the dead link, not very useful :-)

Comment: Would you open a bug for the broken link issue on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio)?  It might be a trivial issue in the grand scheme of things, but it's important that it get fixed.  [As for your actual question, I cannot help you; that's way outside my experience with managed code. :-)  Hopefully someone else here can help.]

Comment: Have you tried using the `dynamic` keyword? Does it work then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does the call fail when invoked via reflection and not when I call it directly ?

Answer: `WindowsRuntimeMarshal.AddEventHandler` is marked with `[SecurityCritical]` attribute

From *Security Considerations for Reflection*: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stfy7tfc.aspx

> Subject to necessary permissions, code can use reflection to perform the following kinds of access:
>   *Access **public** members that are **not security-critical***.

So, you cannot use reflection security-critical methods like `AddEventHandler` even if they are public. You can freely call such methods without using reflection and you can freely reflect your own methods. This is why your solution works.

Comment: well that's is the reason why it cant be reflected it has the security critical attribute

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of doing this, after some tinkering about:

First, I declared this method:

```
    private static void AddEventHandler<T>(Func<T,EventRegistrationToken> add, Action<EventRegistrationToken> remove, T handler)
    {
        WindowsRuntimeMarshal.AddEventHandler(add, remove, handler);            
    }
```

And then I can call that via reflection:

```
    var closedAddMethod = GetAddEventHandlerMethodInfo(handlerType);
    closedAddMethod.Invoke(null, new[] {add, remove, actualDelegate});
```

Where `GetAddEventHandlerMethodInfo` is:

```
    private static MethodInfo GetAddEventHandlerMethodInfo(Type handlerType)
    {
        var rtMarshalType = typeof (AttachedCommand);
        var eventHandlerMethod = rtMarshalType.GetRuntimeMethods().Single(x => x.IsStatic && x.Name == "AddEventHandler");
        MethodInfo closedAddMethod = eventHandlerMethod.MakeGenericMethod(handlerType);
        return closedAddMethod;
    }
```

This works. As mentioned in the question, this *does not work* with out the intermediate method on my own class (ie. with WindowsRunTimeMarshal.AddEventHandler as the direct target of the `MethodInfo`). I cannot explain why this is the case, but this is a viable workaround, so I'll leave it here if anyone else has the same problem.

I don't know if this happens because Microsoft tries to guard against some unintended use, or something else - if anyone actually knows why the former method described in the original question does not work; **please** leave an answer.

Comment: see my answer, the reason is to keep the machine secured from the applications this is by design as far as I know just like it was done on Silverlight.

Comment: I would be curious to see how this goes on app submission to the store.  Please comment back if you get through without problems, or with any comments they have for you on this.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The reflected method does not work because of platform security, just like Silverlight was to ensure applications run with in the sandbox and don't effect the .net core framework or exploit the framework to over come the security measures put in place. This unfortunately effect other things like genuine uses of the functionality. Microsoft will not let you reflect into platform classes and methods that could potentially be exploited.

Unfortunately like Silverlight some part of WinRT are locked down to keep applications in the sandboxed but that is not the whole reason however some API are still not developed.

Driis you are right your best bet is to create a wrapper method that encapsulates the AddEventHandler.

You can see a working example below, it would be simple to create the write reflection call to AssignEvent. This example assumes you have a textblock called "hellow" and a button called "button" on the screen.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    RoutedEventHandler handler = (a, b) => this.Hellow.Text = "MUAHAHAH";
    // you can quite easily reflect the method below.
    this.AssignEvent<RoutedEventHandler>(this.button, "Click", handler);
}

private void AssignEvent<T1>(object instance, string eventName, T1 handler)
{
    var runtimeEvent = instance.GetType().GetRuntimeEvent(eventName);
    var handlerType = runtimeEvent.EventHandlerType;
    Func<T1, EventRegistrationToken> add = (a) => { return (EventRegistrationToken)runtimeEvent.AddMethod.Invoke(instance, new object[] { a }); };
    Action<EventRegistrationToken> remove = (a) => { runtimeEvent.RemoveMethod.Invoke(runtimeEvent, new object[] { a }); };

    WindowsRuntimeMarshal.AddEventHandler<T1>(add, remove, handler);
}
```

Ark-kun answer is correct because the method is decorated with [Security Critical Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securitycriticalattribute.aspx) it can not be reflected by normal means. This again to protect the platform.

As he said the [security considerations for reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stfy7tfc.aspx) explains everything.